# Returning response using Jersey REStful web services?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, java-ee-7

I am using JAX-RS web services (Jersey). I have a  pojo **User.java**. This pojo is not generated from XSD. This pojo is handwritten. **Can i return such a pojo using REStful web service method**? Also, is it mandatory to write XSD while using Restful WEbservices?

```
@GET
@Produces ("application/xml")
public List<User> getUsersAll() {
    List<User> als=null;
    try {
        als= UserService.getInstance().getUserAll();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return als;
}
```

Is above code possible without jaxb generated object User,java and only with handwritten User.java? 
Also, is it good practice to write XSD always?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can I return such a pojo using RESTful web service method?

---> Yes, you can.

Also, is it mandatory to write XSD while using RESTful web services?

---> No, it's not mandatory have an XSD.

Normally it's good to generate or write an XSD
even if you wrote the Java class by hand. 
That's because people/clients using your WS will
probably want some "model" from you which basically 
means they want an XSD.

For Jersey you can do this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>test-rest-service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.test.rest.resource</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Tomcat will scan this package and look for resources 
there which are mapped to URL paths via annotations. The 
WADL will be auto-generated at runtime. But this WADL will
not have XSDs which the client can use to validate the
data it sends.

Comment: peter, Thanks for your reply. If there is no XSD then does WADL gets generated? Thanks!

Comment: @user755806 Depends which framework/web container you use exactly. I've done this same thing you did (write Java code by hand), and the WADL is generated automatically from the Java classes at runtime.

Comment: I am using Jersey and Tomcat.

Comment: Perfect. I was using the same.

Comment: Consider an example...i have a web method which accepts a parameter User. In this case how come client sends a request which has User? he should have same class right? Thanks!

Comment: No, client doesn't need to have your classes. Everything happens over HTTP so client can do simple GET/POST request. Technically it does not need WADL too.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43742/discussion-between-user755806-and-peter-petrov)